# Very Strange Double Free Glibc Error

Tags: c++, glibc

Below I have the piece of code that is showing very strange behavior:

```
cout<<"Destructing Output "<<(int)output_ptr->keTotalFlag<<endl;
delete output_ptr;
cout<<"Destructed output" <<endl;
```

The above three lines are within the destructor of another class called Simulation. output_ptr is a pointer of Output type and is a public data member of the Sim class. There is a circular dependence between the Output and Sim class, so earlier in the code execution, Simulation allocates memory to the pointer output as follows:

```
output_ptr = new Output(this);
```

The strange behavior I am seeing is that I am able to see the result of the "Destructing Output" cout statement where a member of the Output class is accessed, therefore, clearly the memory allocated to the output_ptr has not been cleared yet. However, when the delete statement is processed, I get a glibc error because of a double free.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening? If you are interested, I have attached the structure of the output class and also the stack trace from the segfault.

Thank you!

Siddharth

The following is the definition of the output class:

```
class Output {


public:

string outputDir;
vector<double_or_float> keTotal;
vector <int> nPart;

vector<int> pPosWriteIndices; //vector ints store which particles' positions and velocities must be written
vector<int> pVelWriteIndices;

bool particleRFlag; //particle position and velocity write flags
bool particleVFlag;

bool chargeDensityFlag;
bool potentialFlag;
bool eFieldFlag;
bool bFieldFlag;
bool surfChargeFlag;
bool keTotalFlag;
bool nPartFlag;


//text associates output quantity with nsteps and also filenamesuffix.
unordered_map<string,string> fileNameSuffix;
unordered_map<string,int> nStepGridData; //grid data written out every nStepGridData steps


Simulation *sim;
Output(Simulation *sim_input); //constructor
//Some public member functions follow that utilize the data members
}
```

The following is the stack trace from the error:

```
 *** Error in `bin/pic_testing': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000000d60110 ***
 Destructing Output 1
 *** Process received signal ***
 Signal: Aborted (6)
 Signal code:  (-6)
 [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340) [0x7f0d4a2fa340]
 [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39) [0x7f0d49f5bcc9]
 [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f0d49f5f0d8]
 [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73394) [0x7f0d49f98394]
 [ 4] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7f66e) [0x7f0d49fa466e]
 [ 5] bin/pic_testing(_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim+0x20) [0x4d0046]
 [ 6] bin/pic_testing(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIiSaIiEE13_M_deallocateEPim+0x32) [0x4ccb8a]
 [ 7] bin/pic_testing(_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIiSaIiEED2Ev+0x41) [0x4ca32d]
 [ 8] bin/pic_testing(_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEED2Ev+0x41) [0x4c8705]
 [ 9] bin/pic_testing(_ZN6OutputD1Ev+0x5e) [0x4c7be8]
 [10] bin/pic_testing(_ZN10SimulationD1Ev+0x10b) [0x4bf00b]
 [11] bin/pic_testing(main+0x3b0) [0x4b8ac4]
 [12] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f0d49f46ec5]
 [13] bin/pic_testing() [0x4b83b9]
 *** End of error message ***
```

Comment: Sometimes, when you see a `std::cout` printing after a critical error message, it is because the error output print faster than your standard output. Could you try the same thing but by printing your messages in `std::cerr`? Additionally, if your problem is an invalid free, we probably need to see your destructor.

Comment: The problem could also be in your `double_or_float` class.

Comment: you should show more code like ~Output()

Comment: I haven't defined a custom destructor. Is that a potential problem in this case?  Double_or_float is just a simple typedef to choose the level of floating point precision at compile time. I will run the cerr version and post the results as well but when I commented out the delete output line, the code ran without a fault so I'm reasonably certain that the problem is in that statement. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: `therefore, clearly the memory allocated to the output_ptr has not been -freed- yet.` Not necessarily, you can delete a object, use it, and it can stil work - it's undefined behaviour. So the fact that using output_ptr works does not have to mean it's not been (accidentally) deleted.

Comment: Are you following the rule of three/five in your class?  Have you implemented the copy ctor, copy assignment op, (move ctor, move assignment op), and dtor?

Comment: @user1320881: I looked through the code and didn't find another place where a "delete output" may have occurred. Is there potentially another way it could've been deleted?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: I actually had to look up the rule of three after you mentioned it, so I guess no, I'm not following that. Only the Simulation class has a non-default destructor, the Output class only has a non-default constructor. Is that potentially the source of that problem?

Comment: If one of your classes contains a pointer that is allocated in a ctor and deleted in a dtor, then if you create a copy of it using the automatically generated copy ctor or assignment operator, it will perform a shallow copy of the pointer.  So now you have two objects pointing to the same area of memory.  The first dtor will run and clean up the memory.  The second dtor will run and you will get a double free (or you'll try to use the data through the second object, and that's bad as well.)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity: That makes sense. However, to the best of my knowledge I'm not making any copies of the pointer. There is just the single allocation step and then the destruction step in the Simulation destructor...

Comment: Then you need to provide an MCVE.   Whatever the cause, it is not in code you have shown.   Without a representative sample of code that actually exhibits the problem, anyone trying to help you will just waste time in guesswork, trying to work out what is happening in code that you have not provided.

Comment: @Aracthor: I replaced std::cout with std::cerr, the statements do not show up now.

Comment: @Peter: I'm at a little bit of a loss about how to better provide an MCVE, unfortunately. This is a small part of a very long code and the fact is that it runs "alright" (no segfaults, consistently) without the "delete output" and repeatedly segfaults with the "delete output"...so I'm fishing for opinions people might have so that I can explore those avenues and get back with answers in the hope of finding a solution.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, thank you for that rule of three suggestion, I will look more carefully into it. Maybe I am inadvertently copying things without realizing it.

Comment: @Siddarth - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .   The usual technique is to back up your project, remove parts that aren't relevant, and keep going until you have a small but complete sample that exhibits your problem. Yes, that may take a while, but it is an investment of effort to find your problem.  In the process, you might actually have an "aha!" moment in which you realise what the problem is and how to fix it.   If not, then people have a fighting chance of helping you.   Which they do not, at present.

Comment: The stack trace from the error hints that one of the `vector<int>` members is the culprit.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl, yes thank you for reading that stack trace, it turns out that the error was originating in the member vector<int>nPart and somehow flowing through to cause the strange behavior!

Comment: @Peter: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I did start to strip down the code and noticed where the flaw was. I also started to see a different error pop up during that process, which combined with Christoph's observation led me to the result. I'm still not sure why it specifically showed up as a "double free" problem, and even my debugger was leading me inside the delete output statement, but essentially I was assigning values in positions that didn't exist in the vector <int> nPart variable. But as soon as I fixed that, things were up and running. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Thank you everyone who gave your time to helping me resolve this! I sincerely appreciate your help. I not only solved the problem but also learned a lot of extra useful things from this thread!